# remove a div with class name from a string with php

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need to remove a specific div from a string.

My code is:

```
$varz = "<div class="post-single">
<p> Hello all! </p>
<div class="ad">I want to remove this div</div>
</div>";

$varzfinal = preg_replace('/<div class="ad">.+<\/div>/siU', '', $varz); 
echo $varzfinal;
```

I need to remove this: `<div class="ad">I want to remove this div</div>`

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you need to remove it with PHP please use a [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) Using regex with HTML tags will drive you up the wall.

Comment: You also need to either escape those quotation marks or use single/double.

Comment: Your code should be throwing a parse error. You have unescaped quotes inside encapsulated same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are all patient. Regular Expressions are built to be used on specefic cases. Here PHP community made for us **DOMDocument**. So why not use the best out of it?!

```
<?php
    $varz = <<< EOT
    <div class="post-single">
    <p> Hello all! </p>
    <div class="ad">I want to remove this div</div>
    </div>
EOT;

    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($varz);
    $s = new DOMXPath($d);
    foreach($s->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "ad")]') as $t )
        $t->parentNode->removeChild($t);

    echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Comment: AMAZING!!! And if i have a div with class "ad2" bellow the div with class ad? How is this possible to remove it? Also i have an characters encoding issue. is there any way to set it as UTF8?

Comment: Tip: if you dont want DOCTYPE, HTML and BODY wrapper around new html use `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` in `loadHTML()` so it would be `$s = new DOMXPath($d, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed PHP/regex, works for class "ad" and "ad1" or any other number:

```
<?php
$varz = '<div class="post-single">
<p> Hello all! </p>
<div class="ad">I want to remove this div</div>

<div class="ad2">I want to remove this div</div>
<div class="a">I dont want to remove this div</div>
<div> cool </div>
</div>';

$varzfinal = preg_replace('/<div class="ad(\d*)?">.+<\/div>/siU', '', $varz); 
echo $varzfinal;
?>
```

To fix the encoding add `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the  section.